# Is it possible to receive complaint count in monthly format?

Tags: openfda

I'm currently using the following function to get complaints on certain drugs over time. However, the output gives me the number of reported complaints on a daily basis. It would help me a great deal if I could get the number of reported complaints on a monthly basis.

> https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:[20110101+TO+20150101]+AND+brand_name:lantus&count=receivedate

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small Python snippet that takes your URL and produces a output that you can load into Excel.

```
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
monthly = defaultdict(int)

url = 'https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:[20110101+TO+20150101]+AND+brand_name:lantus&count=receivedate'
r = requests.get(url)
r = r.json()
data = r.get(u'results',u'')

for item in data:
    count = item.get(u'count',u'')
    ddate = item.get(u'time',u'')
    if ddate != u'' and count != u'':
        dkey = ''.join(ddate[0:4])+'-'+''.join(ddate[4:6])
        monthly[dkey] += int(count)

for item in monthly:
    print item, monthly.get(item)
```

Gives as an output:

```
2011-08 569
2011-09 505
2011-02 432
2011-03 462
2011-01 439
2011-06 560
....
```

Which is in an Excel-importable format.

Comment: I really have to switch to python 3

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to see stats by month we have graphs on [ResearchAE.com](http://researchae.com)

*Disclosure: I created ResearchAE.com*

Comment: @Skram : do you have evidence that Brian created ResearchAE?  There's nothing in his profile to indicate so.  'We' can mean many different things.  (eg, he might assist with the website, but not have been involved in the creation).  It's better to point people to the posting guidelines, and give them a chance to edit their post, rather than you taking it upon yourself to do it.

Comment: see http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/behavior ... I personally wouldn't consider this 'overt self-promotion' with only one post, personally.

Comment: @Joe I know Brian personally and it looks like he answered without logging into his SE account (http://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/3137/brian)

Comment: @Brian : see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232 for how to merge your two accounts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API endpoint or query to aggregate by month. You can submit a feature request to https://github.com/fda/openfda/issues however.

We had this same question/issue and identified two potential solutions:

1. Like @phileshem proposed in his answer to your question, you can aggregate in your application code. Phil provided an example in Python. I have Ruby code somewhere if you need/prefer.
2. Much less optimally for both you and the openFDA web services is to do many `receivedate:[X to Y]` API calls. I would suggest against this but it is an option.